# How to make declaration files for an unofficial vue module, or any packages for that matter?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

In Vue, I am using package for a custom direction: `vue-clickaway` in a TypeScript project. When I import the module like this:

```
import { mixin as clickaway } from 'vue-clickaway'
```

The linter and compiler gives me an error:

`` Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-clickaway'. '/home/wahid/Development/tealvalley-app/node_modules/vue-clickaway/dist/vue-clickaway.common.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/vue-clickaway` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vue-clickaway';` ``

It's not there in `@types/vue-clickaway` either. So looks like I have to make the declaration types for it.

My question is, **how do you go about figuring out how to make a declaration file for this, or any module?**

ps. I can get around this error by doing this (for now):

```
const clickaway = require('vue-clickaway').mixin
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround to the one you suggest is to create a `vue-clickaway.d.ts` file with the following content:

```
declare module 'vue-clickaway' {
  export const mixin: any;
}
```

This is still a workaround as this doesn't really add typings to the module, but only makes `any` explicit.